# Loading images using UIImageView+AFNetworking Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios9, xcode7

I have been using UIImageView+AFNetworking.swift in my application to download images, but after updating to Xcode 7, it gives me an error.

Here is the full code:

```
import UIKit

@objc public protocol AFImageCacheProtocol:class{
    func cachedImageForRequest(request:NSURLRequest) -> UIImage?
    func cacheImage(image:UIImage, forRequest request:NSURLRequest);
}

extension UIImageView {
    private struct AssociatedKeys {
        static var SharedImageCache = "SharedImageCache"
        static var RequestImageOperation = "RequestImageOperation"
        static var URLRequestImage = "UrlRequestImage"
    }

    public class func setSharedImageCache(cache:AFImageCacheProtocol?) {
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.SharedImageCache, cache, UInt(objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN))
    }

    public class func sharedImageCache() -> AFImageCacheProtocol {
        struct Static {
            static var token : dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var defaultImageCache:AFImageCache?
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token, { () -> Void in
            Static.defaultImageCache = AFImageCache()
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification, object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (NSNotification) -> Void in
                Static.defaultImageCache!.removeAllObjects()
            }
        })
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.SharedImageCache) as? AFImageCacheProtocol ?? Static.defaultImageCache!
    }

    private class func af_sharedImageRequestOperationQueue() -> NSOperationQueue {
        struct Static {
            static var token:dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var queue:NSOperationQueue?
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token, { () -> Void in
            Static.queue = NSOperationQueue()
            Static.queue!.maxConcurrentOperationCount = NSOperationQueueDefaultMaxConcurrentOperationCount
        })
        return Static.queue!
    }

    private var af_requestImageOperation:(operation:NSOperation?, request: NSURLRequest?) {
        get {
            let operation:NSOperation? = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.RequestImageOperation) as? NSOperation
            let request:NSURLRequest? = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.URLRequestImage) as? NSURLRequest
            return (operation, request)
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.RequestImageOperation, newValue.operation, UInt(objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.URLRequestImage, newValue.request, UInt(objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
        }
    }

    public func setImageWithUrl(url:NSURL, placeHolderImage:UIImage? = nil) {
        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.addValue("image/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        self.setImageWithUrlRequest(request, placeHolderImage: placeHolderImage, success: nil, failure: nil)
    }

    public func setImageWithUrlRequest(request:NSURLRequest, placeHolderImage:UIImage? = nil,
        success:((request:NSURLRequest?, response:NSURLResponse?, image:UIImage, fromCache:Bool) -> Void)?,
        failure:((request:NSURLRequest?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError) -> Void)?)
    {
        self.cancelImageRequestOperation()

        if let cachedImage = UIImageView.sharedImageCache().cachedImageForRequest(request) {
            if success != nil {
                success!(request: nil, response:nil, image: cachedImage, fromCache:true)
            }
            else {
                self.image = cachedImage
            }

            return
        }

        if placeHolderImage != nil {
            self.image = placeHolderImage
        }

        self.af_requestImageOperation = (NSBlockOperation(block: { () -> Void in
            var response:NSURLResponse?
            var error:NSError?
            let data: NSData?
            do {
                data = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response)
            } catch let error1 as NSError {
                error = error1
                data = nil
            } catch {
                fatalError()
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                if request.URL!.isEqual(self.af_requestImageOperation.request?.URL) {
                    let image:UIImage? = (data != nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil)
                    if image != nil {
                        if success != nil {
                            success!(request: request, response: response, image: image!, fromCache:false)
                        }
                        else {
                            self.image = image!
                        }
                        UIImageView.sharedImageCache().cacheImage(image!, forRequest: request)
                    }
                    else {
                        if failure != nil {
                            failure!(request: request, response:response, error: error!)
                        }
                    }

                    self.af_requestImageOperation = (nil, nil)
                }
            })
        }), request)

        UIImageView.af_sharedImageRequestOperationQueue().addOperation(self.af_requestImageOperation.operation!)
    }

    private func cancelImageRequestOperation() {
        self.af_requestImageOperation.operation?.cancel()
        self.af_requestImageOperation = (nil, nil)
    }
}

func AFImageCacheKeyFromURLRequest(request:NSURLRequest) -> String {
    return request.URL!.absoluteString
}

class AFImageCache: NSCache, AFImageCacheProtocol {
    func cachedImageForRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> UIImage? {
        switch request.cachePolicy {
        case NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,
        NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData:
            return nil
        default:
            break
        }

        return self.objectForKey(AFImageCacheKeyFromURLRequest(request)) as? UIImage
    }

    func cacheImage(image: UIImage, forRequest request: NSURLRequest) {
        self.setObject(image, forKey: AFImageCacheKeyFromURLRequest(request))
    }
}
```

Error image:

[image]

Error 1:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.SharedImageCache, cache, UInt(objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN))
```

Error 2:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.RequestImageOperation, newValue.operation, UInt(objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
```

Error 3:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.URLRequestImage, newValue.request, UInt(objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
```

Does anyone has any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is exactly as the error states; that `UInt` cannot be created with an argument of type `objc_AssociationPolicy`.

`objc_setAssociatedObject` expects the policy parameter to be of type `objc_AssociationPolicy`, you don't need to convert it to `UInt` at all.

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.SharedImageCache, cache, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
```

Comment: Where do i replace that, and what about the other errors?

Comment: The code I have supplied is a replacement for the code you have supplied under "Error 1", if you look at what has changed I'm sure you can figure out how to fix the other two as they are exactly the same error, just different occurrences.

Comment: I thought so, but i get error on that one aswell: http://s4.postimg.org/snnqi24wt/Screen_Shot_2015_09_23_at_16_00_09.png

Comment: I removed the "rawValue" at the end, and that fixed the problem.. Not sure if works correct tho? `objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.SharedImageCache, cache, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)`

Comment: Yes I have just noticed that as well, I'm sure I tested .rawValue and it worked, oh well I'm in the process of updating the answer anyway...

Comment: I have 1 error left now, it says "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11"? The list is huge, but it looks like all comes from this code: http://pastebin.com/MybyDEkn - Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems like segfault 11 is a known issue with Parse: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/280

Comment: Yes, i just tried that one actually, but gave me error in code: `if let newObjects = objects as? [PFObject] {` - Image: http://s17.postimg.org/6opum9wen/Screen_Shot_2015_09_23_at_16_26_24.png